# Perforce Helix Core cancel commit inside trigger

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to check some file conditions inside change-content trigger and cancel the submit based on that condition.

If my trigger fails the operation is still submited to the server. How can I prevent submit?

Any help is much appreciated!

**update:**
I was using nodejs script as a trigger, exception is not enought to prevent a submit operation. There should be `process.exit(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger needs to return a non-zero exit code in order to fail the calling operation.

Make sure that the trigger is blocking and returning its status code to the caller, rather than returning zero and forking so it can run asynchronously.

Note that triggers that run after the fact (like `change-commit`) can't block an operation, but `change-content` should be able to prevent a submit from finishing.